# Making challange more efficient with DayOfWeek

Tags: c#, list, for-loop, dayofweek

I have this challange that I finished which asked to print out a string according to the provided schedule. Here is an example:

```
var restaurant = new Restaurant(
            new OpeningHour(8,16), // Sunday
            new OpeningHour(8,17), // Monday
            new OpeningHour(8,17), // Tuesday
            new OpeningHour(8,17), // Wednesday
            new OpeningHour(8,16), // Thursday
            new OpeningHour(8,16), // Friday
            new OpeningHour(8,16)  // Saturday
        );
```

**expected output result** = "Sun, Thu - Sat: 8-16, Mon - Wed: 8-17"

What I did was essentially:

- Create a List of Days, OpenHours, and CloseHours
- Create a HashSet of the days so that I can compare the days
- Create a for loop according to HashSet and Days
- Seperate the Start, Middle, and Ending
- Concatenate the result according to the open and close hours as well as the gap between days

I have tried my best but I know for a fact that my code is not efficient at all, instead messy. I am trying to improve my C# skills please help. Here is my messy code:

```
namespace Livit
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    
    public class Restaurant
    {
        public WeekCollection<OpeningHour> OpeningHours { get; private set; }

        public Restaurant() {
            // No opening hours available for restaurant
        }

        public Restaurant(OpeningHour monday, OpeningHour tuesday, OpeningHour wednesday, OpeningHour thursday, OpeningHour friday, OpeningHour saturday, OpeningHour sunday)
        {
            OpeningHours = new WeekCollection<OpeningHour>(monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday, sunday);
        }
        
        // THE EMPHASIS OF THE CHALLANGE IS THIS FUNCTION RIGHT HERE!!!
        // Parse the date into desired format
        public string DateParser(List<DayOfWeek> days, List<TimeSpan> openHours, List<TimeSpan> closeHours)
        {
          HashSet<string> availableRanges = new HashSet<string>();
          List<string> timeRanges = new List<string>();
          DayOfWeek current = DayOfWeek.Sunday;
          string result = "";
          for (int i = 0 ; i < days.Count; i++){
            string timeRange = openHours[i].ToString().Substring(1,1)+'-'+closeHours[i].ToString().Substring(0,2);
            availableRanges.Add(timeRange);
            timeRanges.Add(timeRange);
          }
          List<string> arToList= availableRanges.ToList();
          for (int i = 0 ; i < arToList.Count; i++)
            {
              for (int j = 0 ; j < timeRanges.Count; j++){
                if(timeRanges[j] == arToList[i]){
                  
                  
                  // First Item
                  if(j==0 ){
                    result += days[j].ToString().Substring(0,3);
                  }
                  // Last Item
                  else if(j==timeRanges.Count-1){
                    char last = result.Last();
                    if(last != ' '){
                        result += " - ";
                      } 
                    result += days[j].ToString().Substring(0,3);
                  }
                  // Everything in the middle
                  else{
                    if(days[j]-current > 1){
                      result += ", ";
                    }
                    if(timeRanges[j] != timeRanges[j-1] ){
                      result += days[j].ToString().Substring(0,3);
                    } else if (timeRanges[j] == timeRanges[j-1]){
                      char last = result.Last();
                      if(last != ' '){
                        result += " - ";
                      } 
                      if(timeRanges[j] != timeRanges[j+1]){
                        result += days[j].ToString().Substring(0,3);
                      }
                    }
                  }
                  
                  current = days[j];
                } 
              }
              
              result += ": " + arToList[i];
              if(i!=arToList.Count-1){
                result += ", ";
              }
            } 
          Console.WriteLine(result);
          return result;
        }

        public string GetOpeningHours()
        {
            // Declare List for each attribute
            List<DayOfWeek> days = new List<DayOfWeek>();
            List<TimeSpan> openHours = new List<TimeSpan>();
            List<TimeSpan> closeHours = new List<TimeSpan>();
            // Call the opening and closing hours from each day and feed into new array
            foreach (DayOfWeek day in Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek)).OfType<DayOfWeek>().ToList()) {
              TimeSpan openHour = OpeningHours.Get(day).OpeningTime;
              TimeSpan closeHour = OpeningHours.Get(day).ClosingTime;
              days.Add(day);
              openHours.Add(openHour);
              closeHours.Add(closeHour);
            }
            return DateParser(days,openHours,closeHours);
            
            
            
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public class OpeningHour
    {
        public TimeSpan OpeningTime { get; private set; }
        public TimeSpan ClosingTime { get; private set; }

        public OpeningHour(TimeSpan openingTime, TimeSpan closingTime)
        {
            OpeningTime = openingTime;
            ClosingTime = closingTime;
        }

        public OpeningHour(int openingHour, int closingHour)
        {
            OpeningTime = TimeSpan.FromHours(openingHour);
            ClosingTime = TimeSpan.FromHours(closingHour);
        }

    }

    public class WeekCollection<T>
    {
        private Dictionary<DayOfWeek, T> _collection;

        public WeekCollection(T sunday, T monday, T tuesday, T wednesday, T thursday, T friday, T saturday)
        {
            _collection = new Dictionary<DayOfWeek, T>();
            _collection.Add(DayOfWeek.Sunday, sunday);
            _collection.Add(DayOfWeek.Monday, monday);
            _collection.Add(DayOfWeek.Tuesday, tuesday);
            _collection.Add(DayOfWeek.Wednesday, wednesday);
            _collection.Add(DayOfWeek.Thursday, thursday);
            _collection.Add(DayOfWeek.Friday, friday);
            _collection.Add(DayOfWeek.Saturday, saturday);
        }

        public T Get(DayOfWeek dayOfWeek)
        {
            return _collection[dayOfWeek];
        }

    }
}
```

**Currently, I am still trying to find a better way in doing this challange. Any help would be appriciated.**

P.S. I highlighted the part where my concatenation is occuring, this part is basically the emphasis of the whole challange

Comment: Better way >>> [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Sinatr Thank you, I never knew this existed... Should I remove this post?

Comment: Side note: Your algorithm assumes that the first day of the week is Sunday. This is not the case in many countries, where first day of the week is Monday.

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen This is the case with the challange since DayOfWeek starts with Sunday :(

Comment: If the challenge doesn't require you to accomodate "startOfWeek", then you can neglect this aspect.

Comment: @Fildor Yes it didn't since as you can see in the expected result that it starts with Sunday all tthe way to Saturday